# Value Parameter changes to 0

Tags: mysql, vb.net, null

I want to display the data based on the value of the desired user, I tried to use a parameter that contains the value from the input. When I run the program data can not be performed. I'm trying to find my fault location code, by checking the value of limit_kar that holds the result of input from the user are the contents of the corresponding results of the input, when the **limit_kar** value stored into parameter changed to 0, I think a lot of errors in my code, please suggesting that the problem this can be resolved

I'm using VS 2008 and mysql

thank you

Newbie

this is mycode

```
 Public Function Tampil_Stock(ByVal limit_kar As Integer) As List(Of Class_stock)
    Dim tmpBaca As New List(Of Class_stock)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dreader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "SELECT NoReg,status_kartu FROM tb_stock WHERE status= '0' and status_kartu= '0' ORDER BY NoReg ASC Limit ?fn "
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, myconnection.open)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?fn", MySqlDbType.Int64)).Value = **limit_kar**
    dreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dreader.HasRows Then
        While dreader.Read
            Dim objTemp As New Class_stock
            objTemp.NoReg_ = dreader.Item("NoReg")
            'objTemp.NoPin_ = dreader.Item("NoPin")
            'objTemp.status_ = dreader.Item("status")
            objTemp.status_kartu_ = dreader.Item("status_kartu")
            tmpBaca.Add(objTemp)
        End While
    Else
        MsgBox("Not Found")
    End If
    myconnection.close()
    Return tmpBaca
    'dreader.Close()
End Function
```

Comment: **limit_kar** always changes 0

Comment: Put breakpoint in this line `Public Function Tampil_Stock(ByVal limit_kar As Integer) As List(Of Class_stock)` and check the value

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your parameter declaration is incorrect. Look at the example here : http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("?fn", MySqlDbType.Int64)).Value = limit_kar
```

This looks odd to me. Shouldn't Add take the value as parameter ? What is "?fn" ? Does Add really return the new MysqlParameter instance ?

The following sticks to the example from the docs. I still don't understand the reason why you are using `?fn` and why you declare the type explicitly as `MySqlDbType.Int64`.

```
sql = "SELECT NoReg,status_kartu FROM tb_stock WHERE status= '0' and status_kartu= '0' ORDER BY NoReg ASC Limit ?"
cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, myconnection.open)
cmd.Parameters.Add("limit_kar", limit_kar)
```

Comment: I never used this, so I'm infering above only from the doc examples.